# Linking and importing an Access crosstab query into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

How can I import a crosstab query into Excel and also link it?

These are my steps to import the data from the cross tab query.
Data >> Import External Data >> New Database Query >> MS Access Data Source* >> browse to my database >> select the crosstab query name >> select data.

I need to link the query because there will be additional information to be inputted. E.g. This month is November and I need to enter the data received for this month into the system.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually "cheat" with access and Excel and get it done without any code by wrapping your crosstab query in a non-crosstab query.

First, in Access make a new query "My Non-Crosstab Crosstab"and for the source of the query select your Crosstab query that Excel refuses to see.  Output all columns in the table using the * field as the output.

This new query will now contain everything in your Crosstab query, but it's not in itself a crosstab query.

From Excel do the steps for getting data from Access via query and the new query "My Non-Crosstab Crosstab" will be available for insertion!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Excel won't present a crosstab query in the list of tables/queries you can select, but it is possible to add it in without VBA, and it will update just like a normal table thereafter, you just have to type in some basic SQL in the connection properties.

Instructions are for Excel 2016 & not tested in prior versions.

1. Create a data link to a different table or query in the same Access database as your Crosstab query (from the usual Data -> From Access).
2. Click anywhere in the newly shown table and from the Design tab click Properties to open the External Data Properties dialog.
3. Select the little button next to the "Name: " field, on the right to open the connection properties.
4. Go to the Definition tab and change the Command type to "SQL"
5. Enter a basic bit of SQL:
   SELECT * FROM YourCrossTabQueryName
6. Hit ok.

This should refresh the table with your crosstab shown.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing the data, In excel:

1. From File Menu select data
2. Select From Access object (table or query) you want to pull data from.
3. Data loads in excel
4. anytime you want updated data, right click on the data and select refresh or select refresh all if multiple links exist.

This assumes the database is in the same physical location place every time and anytime you do a refresh, you have connection to this source.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can't if the backend database is an Access accdb file

https://excelandaccess.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/how-to-import-access-data-to-excel-using-the-get-external-data-from-access-option/

"You should note here that while you can’t currently import Crosstab queries from Access, you can import the data that supports the Crosstab as a Pivot Table report (after all, a Pivot Table is essentially Excel’s version of an Access Crosstab query)."

You will have to import the source data and then create a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

But you can do it with VBA:

```
Function ImportCrosstab(TheDB As String, TheCrosstab As String, TheSpreadsheet As String)
 'requires a reference to the  Microsoft Office Access Database Engine 12.0 Object Library
 'e.g.ImportCrosstab "C:\Databases\Newdatabase.accdb", "Q_stage_crosstab", "CompliancebyStage"

 Dim db As Database
 Dim qdf As QueryDef
 Dim rs As Recordset
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim strConnection As String
 Dim j As Long
 Dim xls As Object    'your Excel.Application with sheet activated

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TheSpreadsheet)


 Set db = OpenDatabase(TheDB)
 Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(TheCrosstab)
 Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
 With ws
     For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
         .Cells(1, j + 1).Value = rs.Fields(j).Name
     Next
     .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
 End With
 rs.Close
End Function
```